# Windows service cannot access shared folder at boot time until manually started or Windows Explorer fiddled

Tags: windows-services, reboot, network-share, shared-directory

I have a Windows service running in local system that simply keeps trying to access a file with a UNC path of the form \\machine\folder\file.txt until it succeeds. It succeeds immediately when I start the service manually, but on reboot it gets System Error 53 (Network Path not found) until I do something such as logoff or "fiddle" with [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) such as double-clicking an unrelated text file (weird, I know). But there is no reliable trick; I am not sure what triggers it to suddenly be able to see the shared folder.

However, I chanced upon an apparently reliable "solution," which is to attempt a CreateProcess on "net use I: \\machine\folder" from within the service to map the shared folder before attempting to access it (I continue using the UNC path, not I:). The `net use` call appears to immediately trigger my ability to access the shared folder from the service despite the fact that the `net use` call itself probably fails (I haven't checked because you're not even supposed to be able to map drives from a service).

This sounds similar to [database connection doesn’t work when service starts at boot but works when it’s manually started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687489/database-connection-doesnt-work-when-service-starts-at-boot-but-works-when-its) but in my case it is a network shared folder, plus I know it can also suddenly just start working under the circumstances described above.

I don't think this is a permissions issue because it demonstrates full access capabilities on the shared folder when it succeeds in gaining access. But I would like to know the reason so I can handle it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LocalSystem account does not have an actual login or password and so will attempt to connect to the share with computer credentials if on a domain, else anonymously.  For this to work, the share will need to allow access to the computer account (usually the hostname with `$` appended) or allow guest access with no password.

A better practice would probably be to create a new domain account for the service to run in, and set permissions appropriately for the new account.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the service with a set of domain credentials?

Comment: Since I have access as is, I didn't try different credentials.

Comment: See Jeffrey's reply. He gives an explanation of why you should explicitly assign credentials to run the service. Short answer = "LocalSystem" account that is used by default may not have access to share

Comment: These links may help too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28VS.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981%28VS.85%29.aspx